# How to undo/redo drawing polyline

Tags: arcgis-10.2, arcobjects, line

I want to draw a custom polyline using mouse click events in an AddIn.Tool project without esri's build-in interfaces eg. `Rubberband`, `IDisplayFeedback` or `IShapeConstuct`.

I got problems pushing caches into operation Stack while drawing sketch every time mousedown event adds a point to polyline. I cannot use "Ctrl + Z"
to undo the sketch and roll back to previous cache.

Here is the example code, any suggestions are welcome.

```c#
    protected override void OnMouseDown(MouseEventArgs args)
    {
        // step 1 : init operationstack
        m_editor.StartOperation();
        m_edSketch.GeometryType = esriGeometryType.esriGeometryPolyline;
        ISketchOperation pso = new SketchOperationClass();
        pso.MenuString_2 = "sketchoperation";
        pso.Start(m_editor);

        if (m_polyLine == null)
        {
            m_polyLine = new PolylineClass();
        }

        // step 2 : add point to m_polyLine
        IMxDocument _mxDocument = ArcMap.Application.Document as IMxDocument;
        IScreenDisplay _screenDisplay = _mxDocument.ActivatedView.ScreenDisplay;
        IPoint _point = _screenDisplay.DisplayTransformation.ToMapPoint(args.X, args.Y);

        IPointCollection _pointCollection = m_polyLine as IPointCollection;
        _pointCollection.AddPoint(_point);

        // step 3 : add m_polyLine to map
        IRgbColor _rgbColor = new RgbColor();
        _rgbColor.Red = 255;
        ISimpleLineSymbol _simpleLineSymbol = new SimpleLineSymbolClass();
        _simpleLineSymbol.Color = _rgbColor as IColor;

        IGraphicsContainer _graphicsContainer
            = (IGraphicsContainer)_mxDocument.ActivatedView.FocusMap;

        ILineElement _lineElement = new LineElementClass();
        _lineElement.Symbol = _simpleLineSymbol;
        IElement _element = (IElement)_lineElement;
        if (!(_element == null))
        {
            _element.Geometry = m_polyLine as IGeometry;
            _graphicsContainer.DeleteAllElements();
            _graphicsContainer.AddElement(_element, 0);
        }


        // step 4 : draw m_polyLine using screenDisplay
        _screenDisplay.StartDrawing(_screenDisplay.hDC, Convert.ToInt16(esriScreenCache.esriNoScreenCache));
        _screenDisplay.SetSymbol(_simpleLineSymbol as ISymbol);
        _screenDisplay.DrawPolyline(m_polyLine);
        _screenDisplay.FinishDrawing();


        // step 5 : reflash screenDisplay
        short _screenCacheID = _mxDocument.ActivatedView.get_ScreenCacheID(
            esriViewDrawPhase.esriViewGraphics, null);
        _screenDisplay.Invalidate(null, true, _screenCacheID);

        // step 6 : push operationstack
        m_edSketch.RefreshSketch();
        //m_edSketch.FinishSketch();
        pso.Finish(m_polyLine.Envelope);
        m_editor.StopOperation("stopoperation");
    }
```

Comment: I think your first problem is that you start and stop the operation on the mousedown event, you need only start the operation if not already started and finish on the last point (right click perhaps). Add your point to a pointcollection of type path and then wire your OnKeyDown event to listen for Ctrl + Z if you want to do it that way. Draw your line in the IActiveViewEvents::ViewRefreshed and call partial refresh in your OnMouseDown which will fire the event to draw your line.. you can't do this **all** in one event. Why is it that you don't want to use IRubberBand? It would make this easy.

Comment: Note: It's not a good idea to start your variable names with an underscore, you could accidentally clash with a builtin variable, though I suspect your crash is due to creating a polyline with only one point and without adding your pointcollection as PathClass to construct your polyline as IGeometryCollection.